# pass parameter to pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to switch from using a freestyle Jenkins build to a pipeline project.

I like many things about it, but I wish that I could use the multibranch pipeline as that matches our company a bit better, but at present that is a not an option.

What we do currently is create a new build job with the name of `<project name> - <environment>`.

So I need to keep that going for now. I have a basic outline of a script that I can either copy and paste into the box or even better is to use the jenkins file from scm.

I like this one the most and that is what I'm currently using on my local Jenkins.

If I hard code the solution file and the environment I want in my script in scm it builds fine.

I don't like that option because that means I'd have to have lots of scripts with similar names just changing the branch. If I add build parameters with the solution name and environment I can easily make the script handle those as well, however what I don't like is that when I click build button it confirms that those are the parameters I want to use.

So is there a way that I can hardcode/get a plugin that lets me add those parameters as constants or environment variables or whatever so it is just part of the job?

#### EDIT

As an update to show what I tried yesterday and got to work for our needs is this. First was that I installed [multibranch defaults plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Defaults+Plugin) and followed the steps outline on their [github page](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-multibranch-defaults-plugin#configuration-steps). With that installed and configured I added a new multibranch project, pointed it to my git repository. It now found 2 branches (as expected) and used the default config file. So far this seems like it will work for about 90% of our cases. The only problem I can see is if some people had custom steps in their existing freestyle project. But for now those can always just stay a freestyle project.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly what you're looking for is a way to supply default parameters to your build.

In one of my builds I do something like that:

```
stage ('Setup') {
    try {
        timeout(time: 1, unit: 'MINUTES') {
            userInput = input message: 'Configure build parameters:', ok: '', parameters: [
                [$class: 'hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: 'staging\nproduction\nfree', description: 'Choose build flavor', name: 'BUILD_FLAVOR'],
                [$class: 'hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: 'Debug\nRelease', description: 'Choose build type', name: 'BUILD_TYPE'],
                [$class: 'hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: 'NONE\ndevelop\nmaster\nrelease/core_0.5.0\nrelease/core_0.1.8.1\nrelease/core_0.1.9', description: 'Product core branch', name: 'CORE_BRANCH'],
                [$class: 'hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: '4.1.12\n4.1.11\n4.1.10\n4.1.9\n4.1.8\n4.1.4\n3.5.5\n3.1.8\ncore\nOldVersion', description: 'Version Name', name: 'VERSION_NAME'],
                [$class: 'hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: 'origin/develop\norigin/hotfix/4.1.11\norigin/release/4.1.8\norigin/hotfix/4.1.7\norigin/hotfix/4.1.9\norigin/hotfix/4.1.10\norigin/release/4.1.6\norigin/release/4.1.5\norigin/hotfix/3.5.5', description: 'Git branch', name: 'GIT_BRANCH'],
                [$class: 'BooleanParameterDefinition', defaultValue: false, description: 'Enable Gradle debug?', name: 'DEBUG']
        ] // According to Jenkins Bug: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26143
      }
    } catch (err) {
        userInput = [BUILD_FLAVOR: 'staging', BUILD_TYPE: 'Debug', CORE_BRANCH: 'NONE', VERSION_NAME: '4.1.12', GIT_BRANCH: 'origin/develop'] // if an error is caught set these values
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

I'm using the [Try/Catch method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_exception_handling.htm) to handle exceptions and then within the "try" section, I configured the question and possible answers to select from that I want to display to the user which starts the build.

Then, in the "catch" section I've put the default values I want to set in each one of the variables incase an exception is caught, which means that 1 minute has passed without selecting the relevant items.

Here are some useful links:

[Pipeline: How to manage user inputs](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204986450-Pipeline-How-to-manage-user-inputs)

[pipeline-plugin/TUTORIAL.md](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md)

Comment: sort of, i just dont want to ask for input. o ended up finding a plugin called default jenkinsfile...or something like that. it lets me define a default jenkins file in the core of jenkins. the multibranch then uses all branches like i want. i found that nuget and msbuild scan directory for projects and solutions. so i am going to use it

Comment: You don't need a dedicated plugin for that as Jenkins pipeline plugin gives you this functionality.

Comment: Well nothing is set in stone as of now. This was more of how I got it working according to my needs. I'll edit to show what is currently in play

Comment: This approach , delete all created parameters in job.: WARNING: The properties step will remove all JobPropertys currently configured in this job, either from the UI or from an earlier properties step.

Comment: Depending on whether or not you are using a declarative vs a scripted pipeline, there are various ways to just set env vars for later. 

If you're using a scripted pipeline you can set env vars specifically, with `env.var_name = "some value"`. You can also set it via scripts or even set it to parameters with `env.var_name=params.var_name`.

For declarative pieplines you use an `environment { }` block with `SOME_VAR="value"` or `="${params.var_name}"`.

For either, just having `SOME_VAR="value"` outside the pipeline works & you can use/change that var as you see fit.